# How to process MIME format with inline image separated into a different boundary using TIdMessage?

Tags: delphi, indy, mime, inline-images

I have a MIME format as below:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="qawqKLHOZYgscUPhZKw5hacv=_UlERjiEj"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2024 10:17:34 +0800

This is a multi-part message in MIME format

--qawqKLHOZYgscUPhZKw5hacv=_UlERjiEj
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

Sample HTML

--qawqKLHOZYgscUPhZKw5hacv=_UlERjiEj
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html";
    boundary="5SZQJxkhHuQyExC8cj=_sPNysz4gQuoIGj"

--5SZQJxkhHuQyExC8cj=_sPNysz4gQuoIGj
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

<P><STRONG>Sample HTML</STRONG></P>
<P><STRONG><IMG style=3D"HEIGHT: 184px; WIDTH: 194px" border=3D0 hspac=
e=3D0 alt=3D"" src=3D"cid:/Desktop/potato.gif" width=3D495 align=3Dbas=
eline height=3D497></STRONG></P>

--5SZQJxkhHuQyExC8cj=_sPNysz4gQuoIGj
Content-Type: image/gif;
    name="/Desktop/potato.gif"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename="/Desktop/potato.gif"
Content-ID: </Desktop/potato.gif>

<base 64 data>

--5SZQJxkhHuQyExC8cj=_sPNysz4gQuoIGj--

--qawqKLHOZYgscUPhZKw5hacv=_UlERjiEj--

.
```

How can I render back the HTML by plugging in the Base64 back into the HTML? The library that I'm using is `TIdMessage`. For prototyping purposes, I currently load my MIME from a text file. So far I'm only able to check `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type`, but I'm not sure how to access the content. For the HTML, I'm able to access it using `TIdText.Body`, but there's no body option when using `TIdAttachment`:

```pascal
var vMsg := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
try
  vMsg.LoadFromFile('D:\Desktop\Complete MIME 2.txt');
  for var i := 0 to vMsg.MessageParts.Count - 1 do begin
    var o := vMsg.MessageParts.Items[i];

    if (o.PartType = TIdMessagePartType.mptAttachment) then begin
      if o.ContentDisposition.Equals('inline') then begin
        var sContentID := o.ContentID.Substring(1, o.ContentID.Length - 2);

        // how to retrieve inline image base 64?
      end;
    end;
  end;
finally
  vMsg.Free;
end;
```

Update:
I have tried access the `TIdAttachment` using the `OpenLoadStream` as Remy suggested and printed the result but I only got `ÿØÿà`. Code as below:

```
var vAttachment := TIdAttachment(o);
var vAttachmentStream := vAttachment.OpenLoadStream;
var vStringStream := TStringStream.Create;
try
  vStringStream.LoadFromStream(vAttachmentStream);
  vStringStream.Position := 0;
  OutputDebugString(PChar(vStringStream.DataString));
finally
  vAttachment.CloseLoadStream;
  vStringStream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: "_`ÿØÿà`_" are the bytes `#$FF#$D8#$FF#$E0`, which is [the binary start of a JFIF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) - it's exactly your picture as your end user would want it.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I render back the HTML by plugging in the Base64 back into the HTML?

Such HTML expects the image to be loaded directly from the MIME data using a `cid:` that refers to the specific MIME attachment.  To render this HTML properly, you need a renderer that understands MIME, or at least provides a way for you to give it the image data for a given `cid`.  Otherwise, you will have to save the attachment data to a file and then update the HTML to refer to that file before rendering it.

> So far I'm only able to check `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type`, but I'm not sure how to access the content. For the HTML, I'm able to access it using `TIdText.Body`, but there's no body option when using `TIdAttachment`

`TIdAttachment` has an `OpenLoadStream()` method for accessing its data.  The base64 will have already been decoded for you before the `TIdAttachment` is created, so you will get a `TStream` to the actual image data.  Call `CloseLoadStream()` when you are done using the `TStream`.

Comment: I have tried using the `OpenLoadStream` but the result that I got is `ÿØÿà`. I updated the question with a part of the code. Maybe I left out something?

Comment: @Lyn As I told you, the `TIdAttachment` will contain the *decoded* data, ie the actual image.  You are trying to display binary data as if it were text.  It is not. You can't get the original base64, it is long gone, processed away during the parsing of the email.  If you really need the base64, you will have to re-encode the `TIdAttachment`'s data, such as with `System.NetEncoding.Base64.Encode()` or `TIdEncoderMIME.Encode()`